# Python/Grasshopper Question--Getting circle to follow attractor point

Tags: geometry, point

I am trying to write a code for a circle that follows the attractor point I already coded. Any suggestions?

I have tried for[image shows the code so far as well as a rhino screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xBEv3.png) a while, but I can not get it to follow the attractor point.

Comment: Please always add your code as text, not as an image: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors